# WxWidgets in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gui, qt5

I know that Ubuntu Touch uses Qt5, but I would like to know if it will also support GUI like wxWidget.

Answer (score 1):

Only if wxWidget has backends for SurfaceFlinger and Mir, otherwise it won't know how to talk to the display server.